# Find shortest paths between two points given displacement vectors

Tags: algorithm, vector, linear-algebra, path-finding

I have a list of vectors v<sub>1</sub>, v<sub>2</sub>, ... and a point A in n-dimensional space. The vectors are displacements that can be used to construct a path from point A to the origin. Each path can be represented as a vector of integer coefficients c<sup>i</sup>, such that
[image: 1]
The task is to find some (say, ten) paths with the least N, where
[image: 2]
In other words, I need paths with the least "amount" of vectors used.

To better illustrate what I mean, here is a picture:
[image: 3]
The red path is better, since it uses less vectors (less "hops").

I can't really think of a solution other than forming all possible combinations of n vectors, finding the coefficients for each combination (essentially, decomposing OA in the basis of this combination of vectors) and than sorting by N. I'm looking for any ideas regarding how this can be done more efficiently.

Comment: Can each vector be reused? Or each vector can be used for at most 1 time?

Comment: " adding a vector with each layer."  What do you mean by a layer?  Your diagram shows nothing that I can interpret as a 'layer''  Please clarify.

Comment: " the dot product of the current sum with the vector being added."  Please clarify this.  A concrete example would be best.

Comment: @PunnyBunny, yes, they can be reused

Comment: @ravenspoint, if one could sort the paths by the sum of coefficients (ascending), I would need the first N (ten, for example). Doesn't really matter if they are disjoint. A layer in the diagram consists of nodes with a certain number of different vectors (1st layer - OA, 2nd - OA+ci*vi, 3rd - OA+ci*vi+ci*vj). About the dot product: let's say we start at node OA and want to find the coefficient c1 of v1 in OA+c1*v1. I believe, if we set c1=-dot(OA,v1), we get a resulting vector that's closest to the origin.

Comment: " A layer in the diagram consists of nodes with a certain number of different vectors"  What does it mean "a node _with_ vectors"?  Do you mean the degree of a node, that is the number of links connecting a node to its neighbors?

Comment: "dot(OA,v1),"  What does this mean?  Perhaps you mean the dot product of the vector from the origin to OA and the vector v1?

Comment: A guess:  You want to move from OA to the origin with the minimal sum of changes in direction.  The ideal path would be a straight-line constructed by repeatedly using the same vector again and again until the origin is reached.  The worst path would be a zig-zag constructed by alternately using two orthogonal vectors.

Comment: @ravenspoint, I'm sorry that I didn't explain it properly. I've added more explanations and formulas to my question.

Comment: " layer has the same number of distinct vectors."  What does this mean?  Best guess, the nodes in a layer all have the same number of hops to reach them from the OA point.  Why do you specify distinct?  A previous comment stated that you were allowed to re-use vectors.

Comment: It would really help if you made a clear statement of what you are trying to optimize.  The total number of vectors needed to reach the origin?  The sum of direction changes?  Something else?  It is insufficient to tell us that you want to minimize the sum of these mysterious 'coefficients'.  What distinguishes a good path from a bad path?

Comment: Are your coefficients integers or reals or complex or what?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, reals

Comment: Your equation may have zero, one, or an infinite number of solutions, depending on the rank of the system. In the latter case N can vary smoothly and can also be arbitrarily negative. It isn't clear what "least N" could mean in this situation.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, apologies for a poorly formulated question and thank you for this remark. It was meant to be sum of absolute values of coefficients. Is the infinite number of solutions a problem in this case? If so, I could limit the number of vectors to the dimension of space.

Comment: You have a linear system of equations. The solutions form an affine space.  It isn't clear to me how you would select 10 best points out of an affine space.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, oh, I see. But I can select one point with the smallest norm, right? And if I only consider integers, then the question about 10 best points should make more sense. I said reals because I thought that it would make the task easier.

Comment: Yes you can select one best point if there is more than one solution. As for integer coefficients, I'm not familiar with this area of mathematics but I know that methods exists. Perhaps search for "Integer Solutions to Linear Equations" or something similar.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, alright, thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption 1:**

You want to move from OA to the origin with the minimal sum of changes in direction

**Algorithm:**

- Set S1 to OA
- LOOP1

  - find vector V with smallest angle from S1 to origin
  - LOOP2

    - Set S2 to S1 + V
    - IF S2 == origin

      - add V to path
      - STOP
    - IF distance from S2 to origin > distance from S1 to origin

      - BREAK from LOOP2
    - add V to path
    - Set S1 to S2
  - ENDLOOP2
- ENDLOOP1

**Assumption 2:**

You want to move from OA to the origin with the minimal number of "hops" - number of vectors applied

**Algorithm**

This is similar to how a sailboat minimizes the amount of tacks it needs to reach an upwind destination.

Look at this diagram:

[image]

- V vector of movement
- S1 current position
- O ultimate destination
- progress = | V | * cos( theta )

So the algorithm is

- Set S1 to OA
- LOOP1

  - find vector V with greatest progress from S1 to origin
  - LOOP2

    - Set S2 to S1 + V
    - IF S2 == origin

      - add V to path
      - STOP
    - IF distance from S2 to origin > distance from S1 to origin

      - BREAK from LOOP2
    - add V to path
    - Set S1 to S2
  - ENDLOOP2
- ENDLOOP1

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer. You are right, I need to minimize the number of "hops". However, choosing a vector with the greatest progress does not always lead to a path with least hops. I've added a picture to my question to illustrate this. While writing this, I've realized that my approach with dot products also won't work in this situation.

Comment: "You are right, I need to minimize the number of "hops".   OK, so edit your question to make this clear. ( I have asked you to do this several times now! )